# Finding Multistring inside multipolygon using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, spatial-query

If we have below two tables, how can we find data for all multistring(vicRoads_Data table) lying inside multipolygon(patient_data table)?

I tried this

```
lung_cancer=# select * from patients_geom,vicRoads_Data where ST_Within(patients_geom.geom,vicRoads_Data.geom)
```

but no luck.

```
lung_cancer=# \d patients_geom;
                  Table "public.patients_geom"
           Column       |          Type          | Modifiers
    --------------------+------------------------+-----------
     lung_deaths        | real                   |
     heart_deaths       | real                   |
     respiratory_deaths | real                   |
     copd_deaths        | real                   |
     area_code          | integer                |
     area_name          | character(250)         |
     gid                | integer                |
     state_code         | character varying(1)   |
     sla_code06         | character varying(9)   |
     sla_name06         | character varying(50)  |
     sla_5digit         | character varying(5)   |
     geom               | geometry(MultiPolygon) |


    lung_cancer=# \d "vicRoads_Data";
                                          Table "public.vicRoads_Data"
       Column   |           Type            |                           Modifiers
    ------------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
     gid        | integer                   | not null default nextval('"vicRoads_Data_gid_seq"'::regclass)
     allveh_amp | character varying(254)    |
     label      | character varying(254)    |
     allveh_pmp | character varying(254)    |
     road       | character varying(254)    |
     trucks     | integer                   |
     allvehs    | integer                   |
     __gid      | integer                   |
     directio_1 | character varying(254)    |
     hf_1       | integer                   |
     year       | integer                   |
     per_trucks | character varying(254)    |
     geom       | geometry(MultiLineString) |
    Indexes:
        "vicRoads_Data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
        "vicRoads_Data_geom_idx" gist (geom)
```

Comment: In addition to Michal Zimmerman's answer below, think about what result you want to get. You have multipolygons and multistrings. If only one part of the multilinestring is within one of the multipolygons, do you still want to return a match? If so, you should think about either using ST_Intersect, or converting your multigeometries to single part.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html) leads you to switching the `ST_Within` arguments to `ST_Within(vicRoads_Data.geom, patients_geom.geom)`.

Comment: lung_cancer=# select sla_code06,sla_name06,trucks from patients_geom,"vicRoads_Data" where ST_Intersects("
vicRoads_Data".geom,patients_geom.geom);

Comment: but the problem is I want all the sum of all the trucks inside that polygon

Comment: lung_cancer=# select sla_code06,sla_name06,trucks from patients_geom,"vicRoads_Data" where ST_Intersects("
vicRoads_Data".geom,patients_geom.geom);

Comment: I did this its giving truck but not sum of trucks. which can be done by group by sla_code06 but not working

Comment: If you want the sum, be specific about this in your original question (edit it to state this).